# Recyclerview with multiple view types inside RecyclerView shows wrong layout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have a **parent** layout it has some TextViews and a RecyclerView in it. And the **child** layout, it has a RecyclerView in it and the adapter has 5 different View Types

For the **child** recyclerview, i use an Adapter which has 5 different layouts in it that consists of

1. **VIEW_TYPE_LANDSCAPE**
2. **VIEW_TYPE_LANDSCAPE_CARD**
3. **VIEW_TYPE_PORTRAIT**
4. **VIEW_TYPE_SQUARE**
5. **VIEW_TYPE_TWO_COLUMN**

The problem occurs when the **child** RecyclerView has more than **x** items in it. When I scroll down to the bottom of the screen, and then scroll up to the top of the screen and scroll down again to the bottom of the screen, somehow the **child** RecyclerView **shows wrong layout / View Types.**

**parent_layout.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="home.HomeTabViewModel" />
</data>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/cl_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/v_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_home_v3" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_home_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/v_toolbar" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**child_layout.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimens_32dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        style="@style/TextSoftBlackBold.20sp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimens_16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimens_16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:text="Popular Ideas" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_subtitle"
        style="@style/TextDarkGrayNormal.14sp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimens_16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimens_7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimens_16dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title"
        tools:text="Popular events happening during your stay in Bali" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_menu_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimens_2dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_subtitle" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**BaseMenuAdapter.kt**

```
class BaseMenuAdapter(val context: Context?,
                           private var contents: List<HomeViewParam.Content>?,
                  private val menuGrid: HomeItem.MenuGrid?) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseMenuAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

companion object {
    const val VIEW_TYPE_LANDSCAPE = 0
    const val VIEW_TYPE_LANDSCAPE_CARD = 1
    const val VIEW_TYPE_PORTRAIT = 2
    const val VIEW_TYPE_TWO_COLUMN = 3
    const val VIEW_TYPE_SQUARE = 4
}

inner class MyViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    var landscapeBinding: ViewTemplateLandscapeBinding? = null
    var landscapeCardBinding: ViewTemplateLandscapeCardBinding? = null
    var portraitBinding: ItemHomeMenuPortraitBinding? = null
    var twoColumnBinding: ItemHomeMenuTwoColumnBinding? = null
    var squareBinding: ItemHomeMenuSquareBinding? = null


    constructor(binding: ViewTemplateLandscapeBinding) : super(binding.root) {
        landscapeBinding = binding
    }

    constructor(binding: ViewTemplateLandscapeCardBinding) : super(binding.root) {
        landscapeCardBinding = binding
    }

    constructor(binding: ItemHomeMenuPortraitBinding) : super(binding.root) {
        portraitBinding = binding
    }

    constructor(binding: ItemHomeMenuTwoColumnBinding) : super(binding.root) {
        twoColumnBinding = binding
    }

    constructor(binding: ItemHomeMenuSquareBinding) : super(binding.root) {
        squareBinding = binding
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseMenuAdapter.MyViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val binding: ViewDataBinding
    return when (viewType) {
        0 -> {
            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.view_template_landscape, parent, false)
            MyViewHolder(binding as ViewTemplateLandscapeBinding)
        }
        1 -> {
            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.view_template_landscape_card, parent, false)
            MyViewHolder(binding as ViewTemplateLandscapeCardBinding)
        }
        2 -> {
            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.item_home_menu_portrait, parent, false)
            MyViewHolder(binding as ItemHomeMenuPortraitBinding)
        }
        3 -> {
            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.item_home_menu_two_column, parent, false)
            MyViewHolder(binding as ItemHomeMenuTwoColumnBinding)
        }
        4 -> {
            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.item_home_menu_square, parent, false)
            MyViewHolder(binding as ItemHomeMenuSquareBinding)
        }
        else -> {
            throw RuntimeException("The type has to be ONE or TWO")
        }
    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseMenuAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    context?.resources.run {
        when (holder.itemViewType) {
            VIEW_TYPE_LANDSCAPE -> {
                val binding = holder.landscapeBinding
                binding?.run {
                    val item = contents?.let { it[holder.adapterPosition] }
                    binding.content = item
                    root.setOnClickListener { AllWebViewActivityV2.startThisActivity(context, item?.title ?: "",
                            item?.url ?: "") }
                    executePendingBindings()
                }
            }
            VIEW_TYPE_LANDSCAPE_CARD -> {
                val binding = holder.landscapeCardBinding
                binding?.run {
                    val item = contents?.let { it[holder.adapterPosition] }
                    binding.content = item
                    root.setOnClickListener { AllWebViewActivityV2.startThisActivity(context, item?.title ?: "",
                            item?.url ?: "") }
                    executePendingBindings()
                }
            }
            VIEW_TYPE_TWO_COLUMN -> {
                val binding = holder.twoColumnBinding
                binding?.run {
                    val item = contents?.let { it[holder.adapterPosition] }
                    binding.content = item
                    root.setOnClickListener { AllWebViewActivityV2.startThisActivity(context, item?.title ?: "",
                            item?.url ?: "") }
                    executePendingBindings()
                }
            }
            VIEW_TYPE_PORTRAIT -> {
                val binding = holder.portraitBinding
                binding?.run {
                    val item = contents?.let { it[holder.adapterPosition] }
                    binding.content = item
                    root.setOnClickListener { AllWebViewActivityV2.startThisActivity(context, item?.title ?: "",
                            item?.url ?: "") }
                    executePendingBindings()
                }
            }
            VIEW_TYPE_SQUARE -> {
                val binding = holder.squareBinding
                binding?.run {
                    val item = contents?.let { it[holder.adapterPosition] }
                    binding.content = item
                    root.setOnClickListener { AllWebViewActivityV2.startThisActivity(context, item?.title ?: "",
                            item?.url ?: "") }
                    executePendingBindings()
                }
            }
            else -> {}
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    contents?.let {
        return when (menuGrid?.templateType) {
            TemplateType.LANDSCAPE -> VIEW_TYPE_LANDSCAPE
            TemplateType.LANDSCAPE_CARD -> VIEW_TYPE_LANDSCAPE_CARD
            TemplateType.TWO_COLUMN -> VIEW_TYPE_TWO_COLUMN
            TemplateType.POTRAIT -> VIEW_TYPE_PORTRAIT
            TemplateType.SQUARE -> VIEW_TYPE_SQUARE
            else -> -1
        }
    }
    return -1
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return contents?.size ?: 0
}

override fun setHasStableIds(hasStableIds: Boolean) {
    super.setHasStableIds(false)
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong()
}

fun setItems(contents: List<HomeViewParam.Content>?) {
    this.contents = contents
}
}
```

**EDIT**
Here's my view looks like
[image]

So as I've mentioned above, when I scroll up or down, sometimes some items use wrong view type

Comment: as your question is about UI, why don't you share with us a picture showing what is shown, and possibly another one with what you would like to get instead?

Comment: okay, will add it up soon

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you getItemViewType takes position into account? I can't into kotlin so i can't tell, but no one else seems to bother.

Comment: also for me it's not clear what are you following (some framework or 3rd party lib?), because when you want to support multiple layout types, you need to declare 1 ViewHolder class type for each different layout, and bind them based on the view type ... remember recycler view will recycle the views for each type separately

Comment: @IcedLance it clearly doesn't ... he kind of hardcode the view type info into the views itself, if I'm not mistakes, therefore the error

Comment: @Alessio, please see my edited answer

Comment: @Webster thanks for the pic ... why do you need 2 recycler views? Looking at your pic, it seems to me you won't need the outer recycler view at all

Comment: so, the outer recyclerview has another view besides inner recycler view, like some Gridview, and other views.

Comment: exactly: you don't really need a recycler view for that, a linear layout, or relative layout is what you should have (unless I'm mistaken). I mean: how many items your outer recycler view contains? 1? Note: still your problem is not in the outer recycler view, is in the inner recycler view, see my answer below.

Comment: ahh yeah, i decided to use recyclerview instead of ScrollView, is because the performance. So everytime I scroll to the bottom, the upper views will be "hidden" and recycled again when i go back. I don't know whether it's good or bad practice.

Comment: @Webster the inner recycler view will recycle the views on scrolling. But the outer, if I understand correctly your layout, won't recycle anything. You can easily output some lines to debug and see if what I'm saying is correct.

Comment: well, I'm going to give it a try then, will let you know

Comment: First fix the inner which should fix your bug ... then you can get rid of the outer recycler view, and use a ScrollView + LinearLayout or something alike that

Comment: okay, noted, im on it

Answer (score 2):

You need to define one ViewHolder for each of your layout types, and then you need to use each ViewHolder's class instance type to bind the data on the fly, respectively in *getItemViewType()* and *onBindViewHolder()*, something along these lines:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isValidPosition(position)) {
        Data d = mDataset[position];

        if (d instanceof LandscapeData) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_LANDSCAPE;
        } else if (d instanceof PortraitData) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_PORTRAIT;
        }
        // more else-ifs here
    }
    // default to landscape
    return VIEW_TYPE_LANDSCAPE;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Data d = mDataset[position];

    if (holder instanceof LandscapeVH) {
        // binding of dataset for landscape layouts
        LandscapeData data = (LandscapeData) d;
        LandscapeVH vh = (LandscapeVH) holder;
        // bind the data to the view on the fly here
        vh.myTextView.setText(data.getLandscapeTitle());
    } else if (holder instanceof PortraitVH) {
        // binding of dataset for portrait layouts
        PortraitData data = (PortraitData) d;
        PortraitVH vh = (PortraitVH) holder;
        // bind the data to the view on the fly here
        vh.myTextView.setText(data.getPortraitTitle());
    }
    // more else-ifs here
}
```

Note: your mDataset[] is your only source of truth, and it contains datasets of type Data which can be subclassed to more specialized datasets like LandscapeData and PortraitData which go hand in hand with your layout's types.